# How to link ms excel 2003 to ms access 2003

Tags: excel, ms-access, excel-2003

I have office 2003, and i have develop a database from ms access 2003.
What i want is to link ms excel and ms access so as when am updating either of them both will be updated

Comment: Why do you think you need to use both?

Answer (score 3):

I know that from within Access, you can add a "linked table" with an Excel worksheet as a data source.  This will cause the data in the Excel sheet to show up as a table in Access.  When you make changes to the data in Access, the data in the underlying Excel sheet will change.  Also, if you open up the Excel sheet and change the values in one of the rows, the change will be reflected when the link in Access is refreshed.

However, there can be issues when trying to link Access and Excel together.  You may not be able to edit the same document from Access and Excel at the same time.  Also, if you add additional columns or rows to your source data in Excel, you may have to completely re-link the table in Access.

If you are the only user of both the Access application and Excel sheet, you can develop a fairly robust solution using this method.  However, you have to be careful with trying to deploy a solution like this with multiple users because you may start to get issues with multiple people trying to edit the same document at one time.  At this point, you may need to look at more robust solutions involving a database or SharePoint backend.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben said in his answer it is possible but can easily lead to problems in a multi user environment. I would suggest keeping the data in access and pulling it from excel. Or revisiting if excel is needed at all to update the date (read only reports would be ok)

Comment: +1 Ben M's answer is very good, and this is a good extra piece.